# JSON. Parsing array of arrays. How?

Tags: php, jquery, json

How can I modify my existing JQuery code to loop through a JSON array of arrays? For example, when PHP returns a JSON result from MySQL database containing more than 1 row.

Here is my code. It only works with a single row result.

```
$(function(){

    $('#btn_select_account').live('click', function() {

    // URL...
    $.getJSON('api.php?',
    // Parameters...
    { call: 'select_account', p0: 'suchislife801' },

     function(result){

        // For each item inside array...
        $.each(result, function(index, value) { 

          // Append to this html element
          $('#output').append(index + ': ' + value + '<br />').fadeIn(300); 

        });

     });

  });

});
```

The following PHP code....

```
  function qry_select_account($pk_account) {

  // Global variables
  Global $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name;  

  // Connect to database server
  $dbc = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
  // Select target database
  mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

  // suchislife801 <--- Selects account information
  // Run query
  $sql_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblaccount
                         WHERE pk_account = '$pk_account'") or die(mysql_error());

  // SQL Criteria  AND acc_confirmed = 'y' AND acc_locked = 'n'

  // Fetch table row for this user
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($sql_qry);

  print json_encode($row);

  mysql_free_result($sql_qry);

  // Close Connection
  mysql_close($dbc);

  }
```

Generates the following response:

```
["20","1","suchislife801","Happy","My first entry title.","Body of my first entry.","2012-04-03","15:06:38","n","0"]
```

I am trying to change it so that it works with the following PHP code...

```
  function qry_select_last5_entries_for_user($ent_user) {

  // Global variables
  Global $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name;  

  // Connect to database server
  $dbc = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
  // Select target database
  mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

  // suchislife801 <--- Selects last 5 entries for user
  // Run query
  $sql_qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblentry 
                          WHERE ent_user = '$ent_user' ORDER BY ent_date DESC , ent_time DESC LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());

  // Fetch table rows for this user
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_qry, MYSQL_NUM)) {

  print json_encode($row);

  } 

  mysql_free_result($sql_qry);

  // Close Connection
  mysql_close($dbc);

  }















["20","1","suchislife801","Happy","My first entry title.","Body of my first entry.","2012-04-03","15:06:38","n","0"]["19","1","suchislife801","Happy","My first entry title.","Body of my first entry.","2012-04-03","15:06:37","n","0"]["18","1","suchislife801","Happy","My first entry title.","Body of my first entry.","2012-04-03","15:06:36","n","0"]["17","1","suchislife801","Ugly","My first entry title.","Body of my first entry.","2012-04-03","15:06:35","n","0"]["15","1","suchislife801","Lazy","My first entry title.","Body of my first entry.","2012-04-03","15:06:34","n","0"]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the json output, or possibly the php that generates it?

Comment: I have just included the samples for you.

Comment: Your php doesn't seem to be returning valid json.

Comment: that is valid JSON. Each row returned by database is encapsulated in its own [ ]. PHP clode used   print json_encode($row); Keep in mind I have this inside while loop in my php code.

Comment: It is not valid json, valid json would be more like: `[["foo","bar"],["foo":"bar"]]`

Comment: I also think that's not valid json. A json encoded string will rather look something like this: $str_json = '{"0":["20","1",..], "1":["19",1",...]}';  Try http://jsonlint.com/ to validate your json.

Comment: Hmmmm... let me edit the original post with the PHP code generating this. Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: @Vini I added some sample php code to my answer.

Comment: I had just done the array push and was about to post an update. Sweet! It works like a charm now. I really like JSon. New to it by now I get full control of the data and no longer need php to generate server side html, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your php, modify your loop to create an array, and then echo the json_encode result of that array.

The output should look like this:

```
[["20","1","suchislife801","Happy","My first entry title.","Body of my first entry.","2012-04-03","15:06:38","n","0"],["19","1","suchislife801","Happy","My first entry title.","Body of my first entry.","2012-04-03","15:06:37","n","0"],["18","1","suchislife801","Happy","My first entry title.","Body of my first entry.","2012-04-03","15:06:36","n","0"],["17","1","suchislife801","Ugly","My first entry title.","Body of my first entry.","2012-04-03","15:06:35","n","0"],["15","1","suchislife801","Lazy","My first entry title.","Body of my first entry.","2012-04-03","15:06:34","n","0"]]
```

Then, in jQuery, you would output it like this:

```
var outHtml = "";
$.each(result, function(index, value) { 
    outHtml += "Entry " + index + ":<br />";
    outHtml += $.map(value,function(i,value){
        return i + ": " + value + "<br />";
    }).join("");
    outHtml += "<br /><br />";
});

$("#output").html(outHtml);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/R8wvn/

**Edit:**
php to get desired result(not tested):

```
var $out = array();
// Fetch table rows for this user
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_qry, MYSQL_NUM)) {
  array_push($out,$row);
} 
print json_encode($out);
```

Comment: Dang it. I see what you mean. The while loop is generating 1 array at the time. It needs to instead, created an array of arrays and be encoded to JSON out side the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like `value` will be a json object as well, you can do this:

```
$.each(result, function(index, value) { 
    for (var key in value) 
        $('#output').append(index + ': ' + key + ': ' + value[key] + '<br />').fadeIn(300);
)};
```

Fiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/StefanCoetzee/FZ8f2/3/

EDIT: Just change your php code to this:

```
$arr_results = array();
// Fetch table rows for this user
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_qry, MYSQL_NUM))
    $arr_results[] = $row;         // quicker than using array_push()
echo json_encode($arr_results);    // *echo* is apparently slightly faster than *print*
```

This results in valid json output.